# Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected every time I create a new form

Tags: c#

I'm programming a windows form application which is connected to a database called mmae2. I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a button called btnAddDatabase a new window pops up. Whenever I add a new form from clicking project then add windows form, the new form automatically comes up with the errors:
Identifier expected, { expected, Type or namespace definition or end-of-file expected, identifier expected, { expected.
This is before I've even touched the new form which is named Form2. Once I delete Form2, the errors always go away. 
Here is my code for my original form(Form1)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace @try
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection con2;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        OleDbDataAdapter searchAdapter;
        DataTable dbMMA;
        DataTable searchMMA;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cbSelect.Items.Add("Board Name");
            cbSelect.Items.Add("Board Number");
            con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Ariella/Documents/mmae2.mdb"
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();




            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO Board([Board Number], [Board Name])" + "VALUES([@Board Number], [@Board Name])";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@Board Number]",txt1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@Board Number]", txt2.Text);
            cmd.Connection = con2;
            con2.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con2.Close();
            dbMMA = new DataTable();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Board", con2);
            adapter.Fill(dbMMA);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dbMMA;

        }

        private void btnChoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con2.Open();
            OleDbCommand searchCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            searchCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            searchCommand.CommandText = "SELECT @combo1 FROM Board WHERE @combo2 LIKE @text1";

            searchCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo1",cbSelect.Text);
            searchCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo2", cbSelect.Text);
            searchCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", txtChoice.Text);
            label1.Text = cbSelect.Text;
            searchCommand.Connection = con2;

            con2.Close();
            searchMMA = new DataTable();

            searchAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            searchAdapter.SelectCommand = searchCommand;



            searchAdapter.Fill(searchMMA);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = searchMMA;

        }

        private void btnAddDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that came with Form2

```
 using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace try
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do not name your namespaces as C# keywords and you will have a better experience

Comment: Here's a [list of keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/). Please avoid using them for your user defined namespaces, classes, variables etc.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use a word like `try` for your namespace name in the first place. But if you do, you will need to add, in the `Form2` module, the `@` as in your `Form1` class's module. E.g.:

```
namespace @try
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The IDE's template isn't smart enough to do that, and is including the raw identifier `try` as the namespace name for your `Form2` class. This isn't a valid namespace name, which is causing the errors you see.

I recommend using a different, more appropriate namespace name. `try` really isn't very useful or descriptive anyway.